# Excel: How do I create a formula to sum a dynamic range of cells?

Tags: excel

I need to create a sum function of every value in a row, starting with the value to the immediate right of the formula cell and summing all the values to the right until the first blank cell. The number of columns is dynamic. So, it would be something like `SUM(ROW+1:ROWn)`, where 'n' is the last column with a number.
Here's what I tried so far:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+1)):OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)),0,?)
```

Where '?' represents my inability to retrieve a dynamic number of columns.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(J10,0,0,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(J10:$XFD10),0)-1))
```

entered as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

This assumes that your summing values in row `10` starting in column `J` --- you can customize these value to your situation.

The `$XFD` is the last legal column of a spreadsheet. If you know your data is in a smaller range, you can probably improve calculation efficiency by choosing something smaller.

Hope that helps.